# Django Model: Defining a method on a list of instances of a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, null=False)

    def distinct_attrs(self):
        pks = self.child_set.all().values_list('fields__pk', flat=True)
        distinct_attrs = ChildReferences.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).distinct()
        return distinct_attrs
```

Now I want to iterate on article_list to get the distinct values of a field in article's child model. Thus I defined a distinct_attrs method. However, it will only work as follows:

```
{% for article in article_list %}
    {% for field in article.distinct_attrs %}
        {{ field.value }}
```

However, this give distinct values for each article, but on for the whole list of articles. What I need to do is:

```
{% for field in article_list.distinct_attrs %}
    {{ field.value }}
```

In fact, I want to get the list of unique values of a filed in ChildReferences from article_list

Comment: What is the implementation of `distinct_attrs()` method?

Comment: I have provided the implementation of distinct_attrs()

Comment: But what would it mean to run that on "the whole list of articles"? It clearly refers to `self.child_set`, which is an attribute of an individual instance, not a QuerySet. What output are you hoping to get?

Comment: Basically, I want distinct_attrs to be assigned to article_list, not a single article. I can see 2 ways pseudo solutions: 1) use selves instead of self 2) Instead of self.child_set use something like self.objects.child_set

Comment: In fact, I want to get the list of unique values of a filed in ChildReferences from article_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. I completely removed the distinct_attrs method, and modified my generic class view:

```
class MyView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = '***'
    context_object_name = 'article_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(***)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['distinct_attrs'] = ChildReferencing.objects.filter(***).distinct()
        return context
```

So now I simply do the following on my template:

```
{% for attr in distinct_attrs %}
    {{ attr.value }}
{% endfor %}
```